# Can i have a list with Multiple datatypes in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a string List  time1 with values (00:00 AM,00:30 AM, 01:00 AM, 01:30 AM ...........   so on till 11:30 PM)

I also have a list  appList of a custom object appointment__c.

This list hold only records of the set appointments

ie if a appointment is set for 8 AM - 8:30 AMand 10AM  - 11:00AM then it would hold only these 2 records

I need to create a grid or table to show the appointments for the day from 00:00 AM to 11:30 PM.

I would need to read thru each row in time1 and check if there is a corresponding match to that time in appList, if its found then i need to show the details from appList else it should display as free against the time. I would also need to store it in a list so that i can use it in the VF page.  How would i have to define this list?
Can i have the list store the time in one column and have list of appointment object in other column

Any better way of approaching this?

Comment: Is this grid going to work in blocks, say 30 minutes each or an hour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I'd use a class and have a list of objects for that class:

```
class CTimeSlot
{
    public Time           tStart         {get; set;}
    public Appointment__c sAppointment   {get; set;}

    public CTimeSlot(Time startTime)
    {
        tStart = startTime;
        Appointment__c = null;
    }
}

// ** snip ** 

list<CTimeSlot> liTimeSlots = new list<CTimeSlot>();

// ** snip ** loop through times, and for each add an entry to the list

    CTimeSlot newSlot = new CTimeSlot(loopTime);
    liTimeSlots.add(newSlot);
    mapTimeToSlot.put(loopTime + '', newSlot);
}

// ** snip ** when running through your query results of Appointment__c objects:
for(Appointment__c sAppointment : [select Id, Time__c from Appointment__c where ...])
{
    if(mapTimeToSlot.get(sAppointment.Time__c) != null)
    {
        mapTimeToSlot.get(sAppointment.Time__c).sAppointment = sAppointment;
    }
}
```

You can then fill this list with instances of CTimeSlot, and for times where you have an appointment set it to sAppointment on the instance — this could be made easier by having a map of the slots as well, mapping a time (as a string) to a CTimeSlot.

In the page you could then just repeat over the list:

```
<table>
<apex:repeat var="slot" value="{!liTimeSlots}">
    <tr>
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!slot.tStart}"/></td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', slot.sAppointment.SomeField)}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Hopefully this will give you some ideas and set you off on the right path!